# apt-get update is slow after 19.04

Tags: apt

`apt-get update` (and `apt update`) command on my computer got very slow after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04. There seems nothing wrong with the network since the downloads complete almost immediately. But the step after that (which does not print anything) takes incredibly long time (10 minutes or more). My hard drive seems working during that time.

[image]

I have cleared apt-get cache by both removing `/var/apt/cache` and using `apt-get clear` command but the problem persisted.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the process, the following message is printed out:

[image]

After seeing that message, I tried to execute `apt-get update` again and searched `cnf-update-db` in running processes.

[image]

There isn't a performance issue on my computer other than this one.

If I let the process complete once, it becomes faster in subsequent tries. But after some time, it becomes slow again.

Comment: Have you tried another server?

Comment: Is there a particular line that is extremely slower than the rest?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia No, but as I said, the files are downloaded immediately. If I execute `apt update`, it even says "Fetched 470 kB in 2s (271 kB/s)". Would it still be helpful if I tried other servers?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No, they are all downloaded so quickly that I can't measure.

Comment: In that case no, probably not. Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Try running `top` while an update is in progress, to see what processes are hogging the CPU.

Comment: It takes 3s for me on a VM so it might not be a general problem...did you update from an older ubuntu version? also you may want to add that backtrace as text so this question will be more google friendly :)

Comment: Did you try cleaning and refreshing your downloaded package lists by deleting the whole `/var/lib/apt/lists` folder (as root/with sudo) followed by `sudo apt update`?

Comment: try it with `LC_ALL=C apt update`

Comment: @kenn This worked, may this be related to a long-standing bug in C-N-F?

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney I don't know underlying  cause of it, it seems to be a connection problem stems from user locale.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found/+bug/1886618

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your `command-not-found` package is corrupted somehow. You could purge it, remove its configuration, reinstall it and then reconfigure it as well as finally update it with:

```
sudo aptitude purge command-not-found
sudo aptitude purge ~c command-not-found
sudo aptitude install command-not-found
sudo dpkg-reconfigure command-not-found
sudo update-command-not-found
```

These are the files the command-not-found package contains: https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/disco/all/command-not-found/filelist

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try running the following:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

This might update any outdated versions that may be breaking apt update.

Also, try reinstalling python3:

```
sudo apt purge python3 && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install python3
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: `apt upgrade` doesn't solve it. I can't try your second suggestion because it tries to remove many of system packages (`kde-runtime`, `kubuntu-desktop` etc)

Comment: **Do not ever remove the preinstalled `python` or `python3`!** (unless you really know what you're doing.) Many important packages depend on it and will stop working. Fixing this can be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any old repositories from your computer.
Then run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove
```

and then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

It might work give a try.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

I not at tried ubuntu 19.04 versions so i'm not sure but the above commands may help you.

Comment: APT says `N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.`